# Async function is not working asynchronously

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a question.

I wrote a simple code that mimics http request:

```py
from asyncio import sleep, run


async def get():
    print("Started get()")
    await sleep(3)
    print("Finished get()")


async def async_main():
    await get()
    await get()
    await get()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(async_main())
```

I expected that the result should be like:

```
Started get()
Started get()
Started get()
(No output, just wait 3 seconds)
Finished get()
Finished get()
Finished get()
```

But the result was:

```
Started get()
(No output, just wait 3 seconds)
Finished get()
Started get()
(No output, just wait 3 seconds)
Finished get()
Started get()
(No output, just wait 3 seconds)
Finished get()
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because you're awaiting them 1 by 1. You're looking for [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather). It'll be something like `await asyncio.gather(get(), get(), get())`

Comment: TYSM @KonstantinK. ! It worked as I expected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to schedule the coroutines, either explicitly using `asyncio.create_task()` or implicitly using `asyncio.gather()`:

```
from asyncio import sleep, run


async def get():
    print("Started get()")
    await sleep(3)
    print("Finished get()")


async def async_main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(get()), 
             asyncio.create_task(get()),
             asyncio.create_task(get())]  # Explicit
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def async_main(): # Option 2
    await asyncio.gather(get(), get(), get())  # Implicit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(async_main())
```

Answer (score 2):

just run the task asynchronously like below

```
async def async_main():
    await asyncio.gather(get(), get(), get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # run(async_main()) or
    asyncio.run(async_main())
```